# For loop won't run the correct amount of times - Java

Tags: java, database, loops, ssh, stream

I have a very weird problem I've never encountered. I have an ArrayList of Strings, whose size is usually above 800, depending on the input. However, with a for-each loop, or a classic for loop, the loop only runs about 3 - 5 times. 
The ArrayList is populated with lines of ssh output. I need to go through the output, concat the strings, and put them in a database.

processLogs method (Where the issue is occurring)

```
public void processLogs(List<String> logs) {
        try {
            Connection conn = DMConnector.getDMConnection();
            PreparedStatement statement = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO Logs (to_address, status, smtp_transac, log_timestamp) VALUES (?,?,?,?)");

            System.out.println(logs.size());
            String to_address;
            String status;
            String smtp_transac;
            String timestamp;

            for (String log : logs) {
                to_address = log.split(" <")[1].split("> ")[0];
                status = log.split(" ")[2];
                smtp_transac = log.split(">:")[1];
                timestamp = log.split(" ")[0] + log.split(" ")[1];

                statement.setString(1, to_address);
                statement.setString(2, status);
                statement.setString(3, smtp_transac);
                statement.setString(4, timestamp);
                statement.executeUpdate();

                System.out.println("toAdd = " + to_address + " status= " + status + " smtp_transac = " + smtp_transac + "\n");
            }

            statement.close();
            conn.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

After running the above code, I will only get a few lines in the database, and my System.out will only print that many times. I've also tried using statement.addBatch() with statement.executeBatch() and statement.executeQuery() with no anvil.

Here is the method that grabs the SSH lines from the console:

```
public List<String> getLogs() {


    String remoteHostUserName = "";
    String remoteHostPassword = "";
    String hostIP = "";
    List<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();

    JSch jsch = new JSch();
    try {

        Session session = jsch.getSession(remoteHostUserName, hostIP, 22);

        Properties config = new Properties();
        config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
        session.setConfig(config);

        // Skip prompting for the password info and go direct...
        session.setPassword(remoteHostPassword);
        session.connect();

        String command = "hvmail_report -q all --last '1 min' -a --show-address --show-mtaid --show-time | sort";

        Channel channel = session.openChannel("exec");
        ((ChannelExec) channel).setCommand(command);

        ((ChannelExec) channel).setErrStream(System.err);

        InputStream in = channel.getInputStream();

        System.out.println("Connect to session...");
        channel.connect();

        byte[] tmp = new byte[1024];
        while (true) {
            while (in.available() > 0) {
                int i = in.read(tmp, 0, 1024);
                if (i < 0) {
                    break;
                }
                //System.out.println(new String(tmp, 0, i));

                Collections.addAll(results, new String(tmp, 0, i).split("\r\n|\r|\n"));
            }
            if (channel.isClosed()) {
                System.out.println("exit-status: " + channel.getExitStatus());
                break;
            }
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (Exception ee) {
                ee.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        channel.disconnect();
        session.disconnect();

        if (in.markSupported()){
            in.reset();
        }


    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    return results;
}
```

My only guess why this is happening is something to do with the getLogs() method.

Comment: Documentation says that _addBatch_ cannot be called on a _PreparedStatement_ , but you got this working ?

Comment: I did. My company is on Java 1.6 so maybe that's why it's allowed. I'll change my post to executeUpdate(), since I got that working as well.

Comment: Place a _System.out_ instruction at the beginning of the for loop, and also print the size of the _logs_ array before the loop, to get more hints.

Comment: @Berger What do you mean `addBatch()` can't be called on a `PreparedStatement`? The method is defined there.

Comment: You're right, I was looking at the documentation of _Statement_ : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#addBatch(java.lang.String)

Comment: @Berger I tried adding the System.out to the start of the loop. It also prints out the size of the ArrayList before going into the loop, and its always in the 500+ range.

Comment: So the first _System.out_  prints 500+ times ? And does your _processLogs_ method eventually finish ?

Comment: @Berger No, the first _System.out_ prints out 5 times, while the size of the array is 500+

Comment: `System.out.println(ex.getMessage());` is not a proper exception handling. The message of an exception might be `null` or an empty string. I guess, you won’t understand that you got an exception and which one, if you see an empty string (read: nothing) or a spurious `null` in your program’s output.